# WDS wifi router mode, low transfer speed between bridge to wired NAS

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, wireless-bridge, wds

I have a network configured with wifi DSL modem in standard 802.11n mode and a TPlink router in WDS mode, both on channel 4.

I knew that it was normal for a signal drop in WDS mode, but this only happens with the Synology NAS, when I try to reach it via WIFI network.

The wired PC, which takes the internet connection from the bridge, has an acceptable speed. The NAS, on the other hand, also wired that takes the internet connection from the same bridge, has a very embarrassingly low speed.

**There are no walls between peripherals, everything at about 3 meters distance**

I attach an image to better describe the network configuration.

Where can the bottleneck be?

PS: I forgot to specify that the problem occur whether if I am connected on SSID: **NET1 or on NET2** via Wifi.

LAN setup_

[image]